# OpenCV- ignoring pixels when generating a hue histogram

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, histogram, hue

I'm using the `calcHist()` function from OpenCV in Python to generate Hue histograms for `HSV` images However I want the function to be able to ignore pixels with either ~0% or ~100% lightness (black and white respectively) or ~0% saturation (grey). Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`calcHist`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/histograms.html#calchist) function accepts a `mask` parameter. You can create a mask with this properties that you mentioned and pass it to the function. I suggest you to create something that analyse the pixels once... but an easy way to do it would be:

```
h,s,v = cv2.split(img)
mask = (v == 0) + (v == 100) + (s == 0)
mask = numpy.logical_not(mask)
```

Then you can use your mask matrix in the function. It will ignore the pixels that have false value. I have used this in c++, so I am not sure if false value will work or if you need integers as in c++ version... in the worst case just add another extra line `mask *= 1` and you will be done.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm using OpenCV in Python so I'm unfamiliar with C++ syntax. In your second line of code, does the "+" represent a logical or?

Comment: @user3396592 that is actually python code... it works as logical or